# CharPrinter in ZEBRA Printer XE7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, zebra-printers

I used the CharPrinter.pas unit to send commands in ZPLII for a ZEBRA printer in Delphi RAD2007 and everything worked well, but I change to XE7 and tried to use the same functions and sending to the printer and does not work, and does not give any error message. Does it have to do the new data type versions XE ?

Comment: Could very well be. If you're talking about [this CharPrinter.pas](https://github.com/celioeduardo/delphi-sistemas/blob/master/Comum/Generico/CharPrinter.pas), then it has had its last update somewhere around Delphi 7, so it didn't get any of the unicode implementations of the higher versions. Since it seems to work with streams, it could easily stop doing anything when it encounters the first #0 that is part of a multi-byte character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened cause Delphi switched to Unicode strings in Delphi 2009.
Unicode strings use **2 bytes for every char**. Older Delphi versions used **1 byte for every char**.

So you must make some changes in ***ChatPrinter.pas***.

Try to edit this **(not tested)**:

```
procedure   TCharPrinter.SendData (aData : String);
var
 Data : array[0..255] of char;
 cnt  : integer;
 ss : TStringStream;
begin

 try
   ss := TStringStream.Create(aData,TEncoding.ANSI);

   fStream.CopyFrom (ss,0);
 finally
   ss.Free;
 end;
  // for cnt := 0 to length(aData) - 1
  // do Data[cnt] := aData[cnt+1];

end;
```

Or simpler:

```
procedure   TCharPrinter.SendData (aData : String);
var
 Data : AnsiString;
begin
 Data := AnsiString(aData);
 fStream.Write(PAnsiChar(Data)^, Length(Data));
end;
```

Comment: That code can be simplified by assigning `aData` to a local `AnsiString` variable `aStr` and then write it to the stream using `fStream.Write(PAnsiChar(aStr)^, Length(aStr));`. I'm a little surprised the original pre-Unicode code was not already doing that in the first place, there was no reason to copy the input `String` to a local `Char[]` array before writing it.

Comment: Thank you very much!
The solution that you informed works perfectly - Remy Lebeau and Shadi Ajam